# Cropping text, when window is resized

Tags: jquery

```
function cropText(crop) {
    var str = $('div').text();

    var val=str.substring(0,crop)+'...';
    $('div').html(val);
}



$(window).ready(function(){

    var w = $(window).width();

    if ( w > 500 ) {
        cropText(50);
    } else {
        cropText(20);
    }    
})

$(window).resize(function(){

    var w = $(window).width();

    if ( w > 500 ) {
        cropText(50);
    } else {
        cropText(20);
    }    
})
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NBH2Q/2/)

The problem is that, when window width is less than 500px, text is cropping to 20 symbols, but when I resize this window(width will be more than 500px), cropText() function will cut cropped text. But I need that cropText() function always crop the original text.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can get this functionality natively (with appropriate CSS and markup) - there's no need to use javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your example working. http://jsfiddle.net/q8Cfq/

You should have your variable outside the function so you can access it every time it is called as original.

```
var str;
$(window).ready(function(){
        str = $('div').text();
        var w = $(window).width();

        if ( w > 500 ) {
            cropText(50);
        } else {
            cropText(20);
        }    
    })
```

Then you would do something like that. Because it is accessing the global variable that was set at the beginning. the function does not alter its content.

```
function cropText(crop) {
    var val=str.substring(0,crop)+'...';
    $('div').html(val);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because when you are calling the resize(), you are cropping the already cropped text.

You need to store the initial text in a variable somewhere and crop on it, not on the already cropped version of it.

Answer (score 1):

You're discarding the original text when you call cropText(). The original isn't being stored anywhere.

You could create a hidden div that contains the original text to be cropped, and copy the original text into that div.

```
function cropText(crop) {
    var str = $('#hidden-div').text();

    var val=str.substring(0,crop)+'...';
    $('div').html(val);
}
```